# QML: Sending signals to objects living in a different QThread

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I'm trying to understand how to use QThreads to run a background service that processes data in the background without freezing the UI. While I figured out how to do this in python, it seems that QML works differently.

I set up a small example application that shows the problem (explanation continues after code):

#### example.py

```
import threading
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView
import os


class MyBackgroundProcessingClass(QObject):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        return super().__init__(**kwargs)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def doInitOnTheThread(self):
        # allocate lots of resources
        print('doInitOnTheThread() executing in thread {}'.format(threading.get_ident()))

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def myProcessingFunctionThatTakesALotOfTime(self, the_parameter):
        # process for a long time
        print('myProcessingFunctionThatTakesALotOfTime() executing in thread {}'.format(threading.get_ident()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('GUI thread has ID {}'.format(threading.get_ident()))
    myApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QQuickView()
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)
    the_thread = QThread()
    my_background_processing_instance = MyBackgroundProcessingClass()
    my_background_processing_instance.moveToThread(the_thread)
    the_thread.start()
    QTimer.singleShot(0, my_background_processing_instance.doInitOnTheThread) #sending a signal to the thread to do the init in its own context

    view.engine().rootContext().setContextProperty("myExternalInstance", my_background_processing_instance)
    view.setSource(QUrl('example.qml'))
    view.show()
    myApp.exec_()
    os.system("pause")
```

#### example.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Button {
    signal myCustomSignalWithParameters(int param)

    text: "Click me!"
    onClicked: {
        myCustomSignalWithParameters(42)
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        myCustomSignalWithParameters.connect(myExternalInstance.myProcessingFunctionThatTakesALotOfTime)
    }
}
```

#### Output (clicking once on the button):

```
GUI thread has ID 18408
doInitOnTheThread() executing in thread 11000
myProcessingFunctionThatTakesALotOfTime() executing in thread 18408
```

PyQt multithreaded signaling allows me to run a method in a different thread by connecting the method to a signal emitted by the GUI thread. This is working, as shown by the fact that `doInitOnTheThread` executes on a second thread. If, however, I repeat the same pattern in QML, the method runs in the GUI thread instead.

How do I make it run in the background thread? A (horrible, IMO) possible solution would be to make yet another class in python that acts as proxy between QML and python, whose instance would be on the GUI thread's context. I'd then register the QML signals with slots in the proxy and in the proxy slots' implementations I'd emit a signal from python that would then be passed correctly to the other thread.

Is there a more reasonable solution? Or is QML really incapable of signalling objects moved to other threads?

Comment: QML is capable of sending signals to other threads.

Comment: Yes, I guessed this must be possible somehow, my question is how though. Actually, let me put that in the title too..

Comment: Title updated. So, you say it can. Do you have a link to some documentation about it? Or an example of how to do that? I searched and found nothing (and my example shows that the signal-dispatcher-does-all-the-magic method that works in PyQt doesn't work)

Comment: QML sends and receives signals on UI thread. While C++ or Python can also receive the signal on other threads even from QML. See here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html find "This signal is connected to a C++ object's slot using QObject::connect()". I cannot answer your question with Python, though. The main problem here is to get the right QML QObject to connect signal to. I usually give some unique name to QML item with the signal and find it by name with recursive findChild object search.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qtobject.html#objectName-prop may help to resolve the item with the signal in QML.

Comment: So, if I got it correctly, instead of doing the connection in QML I should make it from python.. right?

Comment: Ok, I had seen those links and I think I now understand the difference. From what I can see, QObject::connect() has not the same effects as the connect() method of QML signals. The QObject version is capable of handling inter-thread communication, while the QML's equivalent seems incapable of doing this. I now wonder, however, why this is the case. I ended up implementing the proxy class and that works because I connect() via QObjects. While I dislike this approach, I dislike using named objects and retrieving them via name more so I think I'll stick to the proxy for now...

Comment: Yes, you understand that is the way to go. Should you have C++ or maybe Python-implemented own QML Item you would be able to expose the slot to QML. For me there is nothing wrong with named objects..

Comment: What works for me is to use a `QRunnable`-derived object, start it via `QThreadPool` and register it via `setContextProperty`. At that point if the thread emits the signal `xyz()`, I can handle it in QML via `Connections` and `onXyZ` handler. I've used it for permanent background threads (despite `QRunnable` been advertised as a "one call" threading facility) and it served me quite well.

Comment: Although my use case has it the other way around. I can send messages from python to QML without a problem (even across threads), it's just the other way that doesn't work as I'd need it to: a signal emit in QML will trigger the connected slots, but they will be executed in the GUI thread even if the QObject they belong to was moved to a different QThread

Comment: AFAIK, if the signal is from QML to C++ then the handler is executed in the thread of the C++ object. Maybe the Python bindings use some proxies internally which causes execution in the wrong thread.

Comment: Ah sorry! I just skimmed the comments not the question. My apologies. :)  Well, again it really depends. In most cases I've used a `Q_INVOCAKABLE`/`SLOT` as an "entry point" to my back-end thread(s). It should also be possible to `connect` a signal defined in the root `ApplicationWindow` to the thread using the root object (as discussed in one of the linked pages  above).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, mainThread(18408) create qml context.That means qml component also run on the mainThread.When you call a python class instance which inject(setContextProperty) into QML, **where you call, where it run**.

Unless you use the param type=Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection. In that way, you need connect signal&slot in main.py. So we find another way, if python class has a method(Slot) names "testSlot", you can create a signal with any name,such as "testSignal", this signal add into python class. In the main.py use:

```
controller.testSignal.connect(controller.testSlot,
type=Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)
```

In the qml, use:

```
controller.testSignal()
```

That equivalent to call TestSlot. But now, is the class  instance call itself, Think about the sentence I just said: where you call, where it run

But this way also has bug, QueuedConnection means it not wait function return,
so if a slot have return value, in the qml you may receive undefind.

Although this issue has been going on for a long time, I want to provide some experience for people who are as troubled as I used to be

Comment: wow, my fault. this way can only use in C++ qt. Because only c++ qt 's signal act like a function, means signal could have return type. So in the pyqt , you need call a signal, and another signal give you return value as param.